# Search в приложении Android

Tags: android, sqlite, search

Привет! 
Кто-то делал поиск в своем приложении ? Есть готовые либы или нужно городить своей огород ? 
Мне по нажатию на `faloating action button` нужно дать пользователю поле для ввода запроса. Вводимое будет сразу же отправляться по query в базу данных, а оттуда результаты. Если совпадения есть, то нужно под строкой ввода показывать список совпадений. 
Я не знаю как сделать это правильно ?

- делать по нажатию на `FAB` создание под `ToolBar`'ом нового слоя со строкой ввода, кнопкой назад и стереть. Если есть совпадения, то под слой подставлять Fragment, который бы перекрывал fargment, из которого и был вызван поиск. Или же есть другой способ ?

Перерыл огромную кучу разных уроков и документации по SearchView, но не нашел ни одного толкового описания по пунктам, которые нужно обязательно сделать.

Может мне кто-то с кодом помочь ?

Мои атрибуты:

- база данных: `DataBase`;
- таблица в БД: `DB_TABLE`;
- запрос пойдет в колонку: `TB_COL_NAME`;
- мой курсор:

  ```
    Cursor query = mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] {
         TB_COL_ID,
         TB_COL_LANG,
         TB_COL_NAME,
         TB_COL_CATG,
         TB_COL_GRUP,
         TB_COL_DIRC, },
         TB_COL_NAME + "=?",
    new String[] { mDBQuery }, null, null, null);
  ```

// `mDBQuery` - строковое значение того, что нужно искать в БД

Comment: Почитайте вот тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/243853/ Кажется AutoCompleteTextView (http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) это как раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, как мне лучше его оформить, если у меня все `fragment`'ы с поиском вставляются в разметку `Activity` ? В самом `Activity` добавить слой, а потом программно в него добавлять `AutoCompleteTextView` или в каждом `fragment`'e добавить по слою и в родной слой добавлять `AutoCompleteTextView` ? О доступе к слоям `Activity` из `Fragment` я еще не знаю. Можно получить или  нет?

Comment: Я могу, Вам помочь. Только чтоб не городить здесь кучу ненужного кода. Напишите, как вы хотите выводить значения и как фильтровать.
Самый органичный способ, по моему -  это брать значения из EditText и динамически фильтровать БД по этому значению, только как вы хотите выводить данные, мб этого вообще не стоит делать?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, так как в бд будет значения не только с одной страницы фрагмента, но и с других, то лучше, я думаю, выводить значения подобно поиску в Google Play - выпадающий вниз список результатов на текущем экране. Каждый результат кликабелен, чтобы можно было перейти в нужное место.\